# Volume bar keeps automatically decreasing

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I have a Dell Inspiron 13-7352 laptop with Windows 10 and I've been pulling my hair out this past week. The volume bar keeps popping up on the upper left corner as soon as it boots up. Anytime I try to increase the volume, it'll automatically decrease back down to 0. I have tried everything and can't find any real solutions.
I've tried:

1. uninstalling sound driver(multiple times now)
2. change playback device settings to do nothing
3. system restore to an earlier date
4. uninstall and reinstalled many applications

I've been disabling the playback device so the volume bar will disappear from the screen, so I can do school work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Most laptops have a set of function keys on the keyboard or elsewhere on the laptop to adjust the volume. Sometimes there are even more than one. Can you identify these keys? Are any of them stuck or seeming to not working properly? Has anything been spilled on the laptop? What happens if you push those volume keys, do they both work? What happens if you press and hold the `Fn` key - does that make the volume stop going down?

Comment: No i haven't spilled anything on the keys and they don't feel like they are sticking. When i hold Fn and volume up, the volume bar does increase, but as soon as i release it the volume starts decreasing. To me it seems like the  volume decrease is being toggled down.

Comment: Boot another OS "big enough" to have a chance to recognize your multimedia keys. Maybe Ubuntu installer in life mode will do. If the keys work and the issue is no more then you will know it's something inside Windows. If the keys work and the issue stays then it's probably your keyboard. If the keys don't work and the issue is no more then it's not really constructive (try yet another OS maybe). If the keys don't work and the issue stays then it's something OS-independent other than your keyboard (I don't know what it could be; this case is hardly possible, I guess). Update your question then.

Comment: Hey Kamil I've never used ubuntu before, can you give me a little more detail or share a link where I can install it without disrupting what i have on my laptop. I don't want to lose all my school work and i don't want to have to re-download all my applications. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have an update to my volume troubles. so i just noticed the brightness keys are also acting up when i use the Fn + brightness Up/Down. Is there a separate driver for the Fn key? how does it work? or is there a keyboard driver?